# Autocomplete parentheses in SLIME

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

I'm learning Common Lisp using SLIME. Is there a way to autocomplete parentheses so that when I type an open paren, a closed one is automatically added? I'm more of a vim guy, so in mv ~/.vimrc I have:

> inoremap ( ()< Left >

So when I type an open paren, vim automatically adds the closed paren and puts my cursor in between the parens. Is there a way to do this with SLIME?

Comment: paredit FTW for any lisp

Comment: Slimv has paredit support, if you want to try out slime + vim

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're working with CL or other lisps, I can recommend to install & use the [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) - it helps a lot to write & manipulate s-expressions

Answer (score 2):

If you have Emacs 24 you can use built-in `electric-pair-mode`.  You can activate it at request with `M-x electric-pair-mode`, or turn it on by default putting

```
(electric-pair-mode +1)
```

in your `.emacs`.

Comment: SLIME came with EMACS 23 :/
I don't need anything fancy, just the emacs equivalent of the code in my ~/.vimrc that is above

Comment: SLIME works also with Emacs 24.  For your problem, take a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs

Answer (score 2):

I think this is equivalent of what's in your .vimrc.

```
(global-set-key "(" (lambda () (interactive) (insert "()") (backward-char 1)))
```

But we like more features in Emacs.  Once you try paredit for writing lisp,
you'll never go back.